# Handle signals in ncurses

Tags: c, signals, ncurses, sigint

I am writing a program in C using ncurses.I am trying to handle the CRTL C signal. In my code, this signal is being caught and dealt with but the program is not termination correctly. Could it be the way I am exiting from ncurses?

```
//handle SIGINT signal
void handle_signal(int signal){

   if(signal == SIGINT){

      clear();
      mvprintw(3,3,"A SIGNAL WAS ENCOUNTERED");
      refresh();
      sleep(1/2);
      exit(0);

    } //close if statement 

}//close handle_signal() function
```

Comment: `sleep(1/2)`? Those are two integers so the result of that division will also be an integer. So this is the same as calling `sleep(0)`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I did that only for testing to see the message printed.. It does not solve anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further research: I'd be VERY surprised if `curses` functions were actually signal safe. It's generally best practice to keep your signal handlers minmal, ideally just setting a flag. So, you should solve your problem like this:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t interrupted = 0;
```

in your signal handler:

```
    if (signal == SIGINT)
    {
        interrupted = 1;
    }
```

somewhere in your main loop:

```
    if (interrupted)
    {
        clear();
        mvprintw(3,3,"A SIGNAL WAS ENCOUNTERED");
        refresh();
        sleep(1);
        endwin();
        exit(0);
    }
```

Note your code didn't call `endwin()` anywhere, this is required for restoring the terminal to normal.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [`initscr` manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers), ncurses installs a handler for `SIGINT`

> The  handler  attempts to cleanup the screen on exit.  Although it
>               usually works as expected, there are limitations:

If you setup your handler before `initscr` (or `newterm`), it will not be called.  If you setup the handler after, you'd have to take into account the various limitations of what functions you **can safely** call in a signal handler.

ncurses' handling of `SIGINT` takes into account the fact that some of the functions it would normally use are not safe, and it uses a different strategy when it has receive a signal (which is perhaps not 100% reliable, but an improvement).

Your signal handler does not take any of that into account, and for example ncurses could call `malloc` to handle some extra output-buffering needed, and "not work", since `malloc` is not a safe function to use.

Further reading:

- [Apparent malloc from signal handler](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2012-07/msg00029.html) (and [followup](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20120825))
- [I need a list of Async-Signal-Safe Functions from glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013202/i-need-a-list-of-async-signal-safe-functions-from-glibc)
- [signal - overview of signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)